# Implement function from C++ in C# (MAKE_HRESULT - Windows function)

Tags: c#, c++

I have such code in C++

```
#define dppHRESULT(Code) \
    MAKE_HRESULT(1, 138, (Code))

        long x = dppHRESULT(101);
```

result being x = -2138439579.

`MAKE_HRESULT` is a windows function and defined as

```
#define MAKE_HRESULT(sev,fac,code) \
    ((HRESULT) (((unsigned long)(sev)<<31) | ((unsigned long)(fac)<<16) | ((unsigned long)(code))) )
```

I need to replicate this in C#. So I wrote this code:

```
  public static long MakeHResult(uint facility, uint errorNo)
        {
            // Make HR
            uint result = (uint)1 << 31;
            result |= (uint)facility << 16;
            result |=  (uint)errorNo;

            return (long) result;
        }
```

And call like:

```
    // Should return type be long actually??
    long test = DppUtilities.MakeHResult(138, 101);
```

But I get different result, `test` = 2156527717.

Why? Can someone please help me replicate that C++ function also in C#? Such that I get similar output on similar inputs?

---

Alternative implementation.

If I use this implementation

```
  public static long MakeHResult(ulong facility, ulong errorNo)
        {
            // Make HR
            long result = (long)1 << 31;
            result |= (long)facility << 16;
            result |= (long)errorNo;

            return (long) result;
        }
```

this works on input 101.
But if I input -1, then C++ returns -1 as result while C# returns 4294967295. Why?

I would really appreciate some help as I am stuck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten the function to be the C# equivalent.

```
static int MakeHResult(uint facility, uint errorNo)
{
    // Make HR
    uint result = 1U << 31;
    result |= facility << 16;
    result |= errorNo;

    return unchecked((int)result);
}
```

C# is more strict about signed/unsigned conversions, whereas the original C code didn't pay any mind to it. Mixing signed and unsigned types usually leads to headaches.

As Ben Voigt mentions in his answer, there is a difference in type naming between the two languages. `long` in C is actually `int` in C#. They both refer to 32-bit types.

The U in `1U` means "this is an unsigned integer." (Brief refresher: signed types can store negative numbers, unsigned types cannot.) All the arithmetic in this function is done unsigned, and the final value is simply cast to a signed value at the end. This is the closest approximation to the original C macro posted.

`unchecked` is required here because otherwise C# will not allow you to convert the value if it's out of range of the target type, even if the bits are identical. Switching between signed and unsigned will generally require this if you don't mind that the values differ when you deal with negative numbers.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what and why you changed? This function seems to work but I don't understand why.. I will keep testing it though. But on -1 it also returned -1 as the C++ one

Comment: Sure. I've decided for the sake of simplicity that all the arithmetic stays unsigned. `var result = 1U << 31` gives us a `uint` type because of the U suffix after the value. We only cast at the end of the function. Since C# will throw a fit if you try to convert an unsigned integer to a signed one if the value is out of range (even if the bits are identical), we have to use `unchecked` when we do it. Both input types are `uint` because they correspond to the C `unsigned long` type.

Comment: Thanks - please just add that explanation (maybe other will also need it) to the answer instead. Also if you further highlight why my previous approach was not working that will be also nice. Like for beginner who doesn't understand these shifting and signed vs unsigned issues. Then after some times I will accept it also if it doesn't get bad votes

Comment: as you can see in my original code I also had casts to uint why that was not working?

Comment: A 32-bit unsigned number (`uint`) fits just fine in a 64-bit signed number (`long`), so no conversion of the value itself takes place in your example code. We don't want to change the size of the value, we just want to say to the compiler, "we want you to interpret this as a signed value." That's what the `unchecked` cast is for.

Comment: No I mean initially when I was getting 2156527717 on C# side, I had casts to uint inside the expression (not return)

Comment: 2156527717 fits in `uint` already. C# doesn't need to do anything to it.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows C++ compilers, `long` is 32-bits.  In C#, `long` is 64-bits.  Your C# conversion of this code should not contain the type keyword `long` at all.

SaxxonPike has provided the correct translation, but his explanation(s) are missing this vital information.

Your intermediate result is a 32-bit unsigned integer.  In the C++ version, the cast is to a signed 32-bit value, resulting in the high bit being reinterpreted as a sign bit.  SaxxonPike's code does this as well.  The result is negative if the intermediate value had its most significant bit set.

In the original code in the question, the cast is to a 64-bit signed version, which preserves the old high bit as a normal binary digit, and adds a new sign bit (always zero).  Thus the result is always positive.  Even though the low 32-bits exactly match the 32-bit result in C++, in the C# version returning `long`, what would be the sign bit in C++ isn't treated as a sign bit.

In the new attempt in the question, the same thing happens (sign bit in the 64-bit number is always zero), but it happens in intermediate calculations instead of at the end.

Comment: Yeah so I would appreciate in general if someone can explain what is happenning there and why my previous tries were not working

Comment: @Quser: I elaborated, does that help?

Comment: I will read it bit later. thanks I can't upvote due to my reputation. I will accept other answer as you say also that one is correct. Thanks. I am not sure now I get explanation but hope I will when I read it better(if you can simplify would be nice, otherwise be it like this)

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating it inside an unsigned type (`uint`). So shifts are going to behave accordingly. Try using `int` instead and see what happens.

The clue here is that 2156527717 as an unsigned int is the same as -2138439579 as a signed int. They are literally the same bits.

Comment: Yeah but C++ is also doing cast to `unsigned long` inside the macro isn't it? e.g. here (unsigned long)(fac)<<16)  ? So why should I use int?

Comment: Because you'll never get a negative number using unsigned types. You're not getting `unsigned long` from the macro, though. It's being cast to an `HRESULT`, which is actually a 32-bit type. When you then cast it to `long long`, it interprets that 32-bit value as signed, then does the conversion, giving you the negative number.

Comment: Can you please see my updated question (second part). I can't make it match on input -1 too, after your suggestion. Where should I use int? Can you please elaborate? and see my update?

Comment: Don't use `long` in any of the code inside the method. If you absolutely need `long` as a return value, that's fine, C# will cast it for you. Do all your arithmetic as `int` and it should give you the values you want.

Comment: Please see my update - below the horizontal bar in the question, I cant' match the result on input -1

Comment: If I call in this way: `int test = DppUtilities.MakeHResult(138, unchecked((uint)-1));` this function: http://codepad.org/mEI01Rg9, on C# side I get arithmetic overflow exception. PS. I don't need longs I just need exact same function on C#

Comment: But on C++ code input -1 returns -1. I would really appreciate some help

Comment: I've rewritten your function. It should perform the equivalent function with the C# equivalent types. http://pastebin.com/MxKDWtb2