# Conversion of HRESULT between C++ and C#

Tags: c#, winapi, hresult

I have C++ code which is called from C# using reflection and etc.

The weird thing I encountered is while on C++ side function declaration looks like this

```
dppFUNC(HRESULT) dppOnlineGetBalanceInfo(
```

On C# side it is declared as

```
[DllImport("dppClientModule.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern UInt32 dppOnlineGetBalanceInfo(
```

Why is the return type on C# code `uint`? Should not it be `int`?

What problems can it cause? It has been used like this now, and I would like to know what problems could it cause?

The linked question as duplicate seems different because the result of MAKEHRESULT (C# version) there in accepted answer is int, why?

Comment: No, a HRESULT is a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement function from C++ in C# (MAKE\_HRESULT - Windows function)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216607/implement-function-from-c-in-c-sharp-make-hresult-windows-function)

Comment: @ChristianKiewiet: Can you refer to some documentation which says HRESULT is 32 bit unsigned integer?

Comment: Refer to Wouter Huysentruit's answer.

Comment: @ChristianKiewiet: An `HRESULT` is **signed**. If it wasn't, the [FAILED macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474.aspx) would never evaluate to true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HRESULT` is defined as a long (32-bit signed) in C/C++. So technically, in C#, you would use an `int`. This is also the type Microsoft itself uses in C# for [Exception.HResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult(v=vs.110).aspx).

The downside of using `int` over `uint` is that you'll have to explicitly cast, while disabling overflow-checking ([`unchecked`](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiEibbov9HJAhUEUhQKHXmEB3sQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fa569z7k8.aspx&usg=AFQjCNEZgwyNIhDsXrgQ2FDv6nVs0RJkSw&sig2=SfotCQubMf91rbUWl7AGmA&bvm=bv.109395566,d.bGg)), all the constants listed in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378137(v=vs.85).aspx):

For example:

```
const int E_FAIL = 0x80004005;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Add an explicit cast:

```
const int E_FAIL = (int)0x80004005;
```

> Constant value '2147500037' cannot be converted to a 'int' (use 'unchecked' syntax to override)

Now, you have three options:

```
const int E_FAIL = ‭-2147467259‬;
const int E_FAIL = unchecked((int)0x80004005);
const uint E_FAIL = 0x80004005;
```

Using the negative values doesn't help to make things more readable. So either define all constants as `unchecked((int)...)` or treat `HRESULT` as `uint`.